# How do you preserve HTML in a jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am working on a project that I want to implement AJAX, and I have decided on jQuery as a JavaScript Library.  Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>jQuery AJAX</title>
    <!--<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="inc/scripts.js"></script>-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery-1.2.6-intellisense.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#clicker").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.aspx/randomString",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        $("#result").append(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="result" runat="server" style="margin-bottom:5em;"></div>
        <div id="clicker" runat="server" style="cursor:pointer;">Click Here to Refresh</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the back-end on **`test.aspx`**:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function randomString() As String
    Dim KeyGen As RandomKeyGenerator
    Dim NumKeys As Integer
    Dim i_Keys As Integer
    Dim RandomKey As String
    Dim oRet As New StringBuilder
    NumKeys = 20
    KeyGen = New RandomKeyGenerator
    KeyGen.KeyLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    KeyGen.KeyNumbers = "0123456789"
    KeyGen.KeyChars = 12
    For i_Keys = 1 To NumKeys
        RandomKey = KeyGen.Generate()
        oRet.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}", RandomKey, ControlChars.NewLine))
    Next
    Return oRet.ToString
End Function
```

I have tried **`$("#result).text(msg.d)`** as well as forming a list, **`String.Format("<li>{0}</li>",RandomKey)`**, and adding a break tag **`String.Format("{0}<br />",RandomKey)`**.

When I run the page it returns as one line, all HTML is shown.  What do I need to do to make it render the HTML?

I got the information on how to call a page without a ScriptManager from [this site](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$("#result").html(msg.d)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to put the html in a node, for example if you have a div with id=container. You do it like so $('#container').html(htmlContent);. But be careful the response you are getting back from the server shouldn't be html converted to safe strings (with character entities). But you are also using json as a datatype. You should use text for this. Or take the string from a json variable you get from the server and plant it in a node.

Comment: I just copy/pasted code from the website i referenced in my post.  changing the parameters in the query gives me the same result as kg's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using "json" as dataType, while you are returning html? Use "html" as dataType and replace msg.d with msg

Comment: When I changed it to HTML/msg, I get this: {"d":"r537pkRW553b\r\n\r\nOzgN1mf3u5 .... <-- a lot more where that came from but definitely not what I am looking for.

Comment: Where does this json object comes from? It isn't evident from the source code you've provided. Are you using a Web Service with json bindings?

Comment: The reason he's using that specific call syntax is to coerce an ASMX web service to return JSON even though it isn't ASP.NET AJAX making the request. It's necessary.